# Parsing nameof expressions in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, nameof

I'm trying to do something with `nameof` expressions in a `CSharpSyntaxWalker`, however, I noticed that there is no `NameOfExpressionSyntax` in the AST. Instead I get an `InvocationExpressionSyntax` for which `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo` returns no matching symbols, and the expression of the invocation is an `IdentifierNameSyntax` containing an identifier token `"nameof"`.

So to recognize `nameof` expressions I would have added a special case to `VisitInvocationExpression`, looking for whether `GetSymbolInfo` returns anything and if not, looking for whether the identifier is `nameof`. However, that sounds a bit iffy to me. Is there a better way maybe which shifts that sort of detection logic to the parser?

(P.S.: I know this is probably parsed like this for backwards compatibility reasons; just wondering whether there is an API for distinguishing `nameof` and normal invocations.)

Comment: [Someone else  has noticed this too](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2015/02/16/lrn-quick-tips-working-with-nameof/).

Comment: There still isn't a formal spec for c# 6, but [this draft](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/f12213c4ffe77a51dbc5412250bef6af75333f32/expressions.md#nameof-expressions) does seem to confirm that it's an ambiguous parse and so additional reasoning is required.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I actually tried finding the place in Roslyn's source code where it determines that but couldn't in a cursory search. Maybe I should look again.

Comment: Nope, do it as you're doing. Considering anyone could've had a `nameof()` method prior to C# 6, there is no way to guarantee that it isn't referring to a method in the class or imported via a `static using`. At the time of syntax parsing there is no notion of a semantic model yet and afterwards it is obviously too late. Anyone doing `nameof` parsing has to wire up their own solution ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now indeed used the following snippet:

```
if (symbolInfo.Symbol == null &&
    symbolInfo.CandidateSymbols.IsEmpty &&
    symbolInfo.CandidateReason == CandidateReason.None) {
  var identifier = node.Expression as IdentifierNameSyntax;
  if (identifier != null && identifier.Identifier.Kind() == SyntaxKind.IdentifierToken && identifier.Identifier.Text == "nameof") {
    // We have a nameof expression
  }
}
```

I opted not to exploit the constant value for detection just in case C# 8 or so adds yet a different operator in that vein, that might also have a constant value, but is not `nameof`. The detection pretty much detects exactly what the specification says is used for determining an invocation being a `nameof` expression:

> Because `nameof` is not a reserved keyword, a `nameof` expression is always syntactically ambiguous with an invocation of the simple name `nameof`. For compatibility reasons, if a name lookup of the name `nameof` succeeds, the expression is treated as an *invocation_expression* – regardless of whether the invocation is legal. Otherwise it is a *nameof_expression*.

Answer (score 7):

`nameof` expressions are compile-time constant. You can use that fact to distinguish it from normal invocations. You can call `SematicModel.GetConstantValue()` on the `InvocationExpressionSyntax`. In case it's a `nameof`, you get back the string / name inside the `Optional<object>.Value` (`HasValue` also returns true).

Comment: GetConstantValue won't help me in that case, as I need to map the symbol to a custom name, but granted, that's probably a good way of distinguishing it from other invocations which usually are not constants.